# How can I set a route for a controller without a default action in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Account",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

However I don't want to specify a default action. Is there a way to do this for my MVC5 application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Account",
     url: "Account/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Account", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```